# NVD3 output date format in tooltip as %d/%m/%y and x-axis date as %d/%m

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

Looking for a way to output the date format in NVD3 tooltip differently to the date format on `x-axis`.

Currently displaying the dates as

```
chart.xAxis
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%d / %m')(new Date(d))
  });
```

and it displays as 
[image: screenshot of current]

How can I output the date in the tooltip as `%d/%m/%y` whilst keeping the `x-axis` as `%d/%m`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom tooltips by using `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator`. Add a line which outputs the date in your desired format. For example:

```
chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
          var html = "<h2>Date: "+ d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y')(new Date(d.value))+"</h2> <ul>";
          d.series.forEach(function(elem){
            html += "<li><h3 style='color:"+elem.color+"'>"
                    +elem.key+"</h3><b>"+elem.value+"</b></li>";
          })
          html += "</ul>"
          return html;
```

Here is a working JSFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/wgmpfa2p/5/

Comment: This worked well. The only thing I had to change was `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator` to `chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.contentGenerator`, without it the console was shooting an error of `contentGenerator` is undefined. More likely an error caused by my setup and all documentation I have now found points for your solution. Thanks again.